# Display image from attribute table in infotemplate

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have added image in attribute table. It looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to display this image into InfoTemplate.

so far I am doing like this:

```
var content = "<b>Name</b>: ${name}" +         
                  "<br><b>Picture</b>: ${Pic}" +
                  "<br><b>Last Name</b>: ${lname}" ;
    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${FIELD_NAME}", content);
```

But it does not display image. It is empty. Image is showing in identity window in ArcGIS, but not in the InfoTemplate.

Comment: any suggestion/help?

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS API for Javascript are you using?